# Can I add an object only if there is the stored procedures?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to insert a record (on LINQ to SQL) to the database. So what I've done is (as suggested on [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) tutorial) :

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

Pagine pagina = new Pagine();
db.Pagines.Add(pagina);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

but seems that .Add() method doesnt exist? I don't find it...

Also, I don't have any stored procedures at all on the DB right now... maybe that's the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Pagines` returns a `Table<Pagine>` or a subclass, I think you want [`InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx):

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    Pagine pagina = new Pagine();
    db.Pagines.InsertOnSubmit(pagina);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Pagine` is based of a view, there is a good chance that you won't get a `.Add` method.